# RODBC odbcDriverConnect() Connection Error

Tags: sql-server, rodbc

I'm trying to use

```
odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=servername\instancename,port;database=testing;username=abc;password=123456')
```

to connect remote database server (sql server 2008). But I got

> [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

error. Any idea?

I can use

```
odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=testing;trusted_connection=true')
```

to connect my local database server (sql server 2008).

Answer (score 35):

The correct syntax should be:

```
odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=servername\\instancename,port;database=testing;uid=abc;pwd=123456')
```

If you use Windows Authentication method:

```
odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=servername\\\\instancename,port;database=testing;trusted_connection=true')
```

Slash seems like an escape character, escaping slash works.

Answer (score 11):

For the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on Linux with RODBC version 1.3-7 in R version 3.0.1 none of the above answers worked. What did work however was the following:

```
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;
                Server=127.0.0.1; Database=MyDBName; 
                Uid=MyName; Pwd=XXXX")
```

(put in the relevant IP address, database name etc.).

In case of a trusted connection:

```
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;
                Server=127.0.0.1; Database=MyDBName; 
                Uid=MyName; Pwd=XXXX; trusted_connection=yes")
```

`trusted_connection` will only listen to "yes" or "no" and not to "true" and "false"

Answer (score 1):

## 1.Connet to MySQL

a)if Mysql is installed in your system, if not install it.

b)download the RMySQL IN R

`library(RMySQL)`

`drv = dbDriver("MySQL 5.0.1")`

make sure MySQL version is correct.

`con = dbConnect(drv,host="localhost",dbname="test",user="root",pass="root")`

use local host or use the server i.e ip address

use the required database name, user name and password

`album = dbGetQuery(con,statement="select * from table")`

run required query

`close(con)`

## 2.Another way to connect database

a)first install any database like MySQL,Oracle,SQL Server

b)install the ODBC connector for database

`library(Rodbc)`

`channel <- odbcConnect("test", uid="ripley", pwd="secret")`

test is the connection name of odbc conector which user has to set manualy

user can find this in Administrator tool

`res <- sqlFetch(ch, "table name")`

A table can be retrieved as a data frame

`res<-sqlQuery(channel, paste("select query"))`

part of the with condition one table can be retrieved as a data frame

`sqlSave(channel, dataframe)`

to save a dataframe to the database(dont use "res<-" something like this)

like user can use

`sqlCopy()`
`sqlDrop()`

`sqlTables()`

`close(channel)`

always close the connection

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to connect to the SQL Server. This code snippet should work, it worked for me:

library("RODBC")

connection <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server", Server = "Your Server Name", Database = "Your Database Name", UID = "Your Database Name", UID = "Your Server Login", PWD = "Your Server Password", Port = 1433)

Reference: [Connecting MS SQL Server via R](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/microsoft-sql-server/)

Comment: Where's the explanation for putting a negative remark on that?