# How to Query SQL Server?

Tags: r

I'm trying this simple script.

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=ServerName;database=TestDB;uid=;pwd=")
initdata<- sqlQuery(channel,paste("select * from MyTable;"))
odbcClose(channel)
```

There is no uid or password on my DB.

I keep getting this error:

> Connection failed: SQL State: '01000' SQL Server Error: 53 SQL State:
> '08001' SQL Server Error: 17 Server does not exist or access denied.

There must be some setting that's off, right?  I know my SQL Server is working fine, and I can connect to it using several other technologies (Excel, Access, VB.NET, & C#).  I guess there is some configuration in R that's not quite right.

How can I get this working?

Comment: I can only tell you how I connect `odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server;server=someSystemDSN;database=TestDB;uid=myUID;pwd=myPWD")` Have you tried not putting `uid` and `pwd` in your connection string at all? I do not use curly brackets around `SQL Server`. Also, is `ServerName` a valid systemDSN?

Comment: Thanks cryo.  I tried a few different things inclusing:
channel <- odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server;server=my_name/SQLEXPRESS;database=TestDB;")

and  
channel <- odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server;server=my_name/SQLEXPRESS;database=TestDB;TestDB;uid=;pwd=;")

and  
channel <- odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server;server=my_name/SQLEXPRESS;database=TestDB;TestDB;uid="";pwd="";")


I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This is what ultimately worked for me.

`dbconnection<-odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server; Server=Server_Name; Database=Table_Name; Uid=; Pwd=; trusted_connection=yes")`

I found the solution here.
[RODBC odbcDriverConnect() Connection Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420999/rodbc-odbcdriverconnect-connection-error)