# Strange connection behavior to SQL Server from R

Tags: sql-server, r

I'm facing a strange issue when I'm trying to connect my `RStudio` environment to `SQL Server`.

**CASE 1**

I execute the following commands and they tend to work fine:

```
dbhandleRSREPORTINGV1 <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=RS-REPORTING-V1;database=Loyalty;trusted_connection=true')

badData <- sqlQuery(dbhandleRSREPORTINGV1, paste("select * from loyalty where loyaltyplusstartdate = '10/1/2014'"))
goodData <- sqlQuery(dbhandleRSREPORTINGV1, paste("select * from loyalty where loyaltyplusstartdate <> '10/1/2014'"))
```

**CASE 2**

When I execute the following command, I get a logon error:

```
dbhandleRSREPORTINGV1 <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=RS-REPORTING-V1;database=Loyalty;trusted_connection=true')

goodDataSixMonthBeforeAfter <- sqlQuery(dbhandleRSREPORTINGV1, paste("select 
l.email,
(sum(ISNULL(o.Revenue,0))) as Revenue,
((DATEDIFF(day, l.loyaltyplusstartdate, o.created) + 179) / 30) - 6 as DeltaMonth
from [<linked_server>].<database_name>.dbo.ORDERS o
join (select distinct email,loyaltyplusstartdate,created from loyalty where loyaltyplusstartdate <> '10/1/2014' and loyaltyplusstartdate < '4/1/2015' group by email,loyaltyplusstartdate,created) l
on o.contactemail = l.email
where o.created
between DATEADD(day, -179, l.loyaltyplusstartdate) and DATEADD(day, 180, l.loyaltyplusstartdate)
group by 
l.email,l.loyaltyplusstartdate, 
((DATEDIFF(day, l.loyaltyplusstartdate, o.created) + 179) / 30) - 6"))
```

Here's the error that I get:

```
[1] "28000 18456 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select \nl.email,\n(sum(ISNULL(o.Revenue,0))) as Revenue,\n((DATEDIFF(day, l.loyaltyplusstartdate, o.created) + 179) / 30) - 6 as DeltaMonth\nfrom [<linked_server>].<database_name>.dbo.ORDERS o\njoin (select distinct email,loyaltyplusstartdate,created from loyalty where loyaltyplusstartdate <> '10/1/2014' and loyaltyplusstartdate < '4/1/2015' group by email,loyaltyplusstartdate,created) l\non o.contactemail = l.email\nwhere o.created\nbetween DATEADD(day, -179, l.loyaltyplusstartdate) and DATEADD(day, 180, l.loyaltyplusstartdate)\ngroup by \nl.email,l.loyaltyplusstartdate, \n((DATEDIFF(day, l.loyaltyplusstartdate, o.created) + 179) / 30) - 6'"
```

This is really strange as all I am changing from **Case 1** to **Case 2** is the query. I have executed the query separately and it works perfectly fine. Then why the logon error when tried from `RStudio`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As per suggestion from @nrussell, I executed the following command, but I still get the same error:

```
goodDataSixMonthBeforeAfter <- sqlQuery(dbhandleRSREPORTINGV1, gsub("\\n", " ", paste("select 
l.email,
(sum(ISNULL(o.Revenue,0))) as Revenue,
((DATEDIFF(day, l.loyaltyplusstartdate, o.created) + 179) / 30) - 6 as DeltaMonth
from [10.24.50.182].OneLegalDataAnalysis.dbo.ORDERS o
join (select distinct email,loyaltyplusstartdate,created from loyalty where loyaltyplusstartdate <> '10/1/2014' and loyaltyplusstartdate < '4/1/2015' group by email,loyaltyplusstartdate,created) l
on o.contactemail = l.email
where o.created
between DATEADD(day, -179, l.loyaltyplusstartdate) and DATEADD(day, 180, l.loyaltyplusstartdate)
group by 
l.email,l.loyaltyplusstartdate, 
((DATEDIFF(day, l.loyaltyplusstartdate, o.created) + 179) / 30) - 6")))
```

Comment: Most likely the newline characters are causing the problem; try using `gsub("\\n, "", paste(...))`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have updated the question. I still get the same error. I have tried executing similar queries (numerous times) in the past from `RStudio` on different databases and I've never had such a problem (I've never had to use `gsub` to replace `\n`). In other words, I don't think '\n' would be a problem.

Comment: This works fine for me:

library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=MYDB\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=TestDB;Uid=; Pwd=; trusted_connection=yes")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from MyTable;"))
odbcClose(channel)

Comment: See this for additional info:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420999/rodbc-odbcdriverconnect-connection-error