# SQL Server ODBC connection failed

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc, rodbc

I am trying to connect SQL server using ODBC.

Could some one help interpreting what this error is and how this can be rectified?

Kindly note that there are no password issues as I use the same credentials to connect to the SQL server using Aqua studio.

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=SQLBBAQA;database=bbadb;uid = "aaa_bbb_ccc", pwd = "aaabbbccc123&" ')


Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=SQLBBAQA;database=bbadb;uid = \"aaa_bbb_ccc\", pwd = \"aaabbbccc123&\" ") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
2: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=SQLBBAQA;database=bbadb;uid = \"aaa_bbb_ccc\", pwd = \"aaabbbccc123&\" ") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 2, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
3: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=SQLBBAQA;database=bbadb;uid = \"aaa_bbb_ccc\", pwd = \"aaabbbccc123&\" ") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01S00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
4: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=SQLBBAQA;database=bbadb;uid = \"aaa_bbb_ccc\", pwd = \"aaabbbccc123&\" ") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Comment: Put `server` and `database` values in quotes. Like `server="1234adsd"`

Comment: @MaxPD - Thanks for your reply. I tried using that. But it fails again

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420999/rodbc-odbcdriverconnect-connection-error) is relevant?

Comment: A handy site for connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see multiple mistakes in the connection string:

`server=SQLRAPQA` should be in the form `server=MACHINE\INSTANCE`. Use `server=.\SQLRAPQA` if the instance is located on the same machine.

Remove all whitespaces.

Use `;` as separator, not `,`.

As referenced by zx8754, in [RODBC odbcDriverConnect() Connection Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420999/rodbc-odbcdriverconnect-connection-error) it is shown that a connection string should look like:

`'driver={SQL Server};server=servername\\instancename,port;database=testing;uid=abc;pwd=123456'` . Note the double occurences of `\`, this seems to be rodbc specific.

Comment: Actually `server=.\SQLRAPQA` is the named instance `SQLRAPQA` on the local machine, `server=SQLRAPQA` is the default instance on the machine `SQLRAPQA` Instance name is not used if you specify the port.

Comment: @erg this has worked. I have inserted the instance name and port. The database has responded. Thanks a lot for your help.