# Connect to Microsoft SQL Server using R on Mac

Tags: sql-server, r

Does anyone have a link for a good walkthrough on connecting to Microsoft SQL Server using R on a **Mac**? I've been looking for awhile and can't seem to find anything that works for me.

Comment: There is nothing mac-specific when establishing a connection. I run a MS-SQL server using VMware on my Mac and connect to it from R the same way as to any other instance of MS-SQL server running on a remote server. You can either use `RODBC` or `RJDBC` package to connect. This [link](http://brazenly.blogspot.co.at/2014/05/r-how-to-connect-r-to-database-sql.html) might help.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm faced with the same issue

Comment: @Taraas Unfortunately, I did not. I ended up using a PC at work to pull the data down.

Comment: OK I solved this. Posting separately.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work for me.

I had to use SQL Server driver from Simba (not the Microsoft's one) and set this parameter: `Integrated Security=NTLM` (I think same could have been done for Trusted Connection)

https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-database-connections-using-windows-authentication/7465/32

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you will find what you are looking for at the URL below.

http://www.odbcmanager.net/about.php

I have never used MAC.  I don't know anything about that kind of machine.

Answer (score -3):

I have never used a Mac machine in my life, but for R and SQL, I don't think it make any difference what kind of machine you are on.  The following works for me.

```
library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=Server_Name\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=TestDB;Uid=; Pwd=; trusted_connection=yes")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from MyTable;"))
odbcClose(channel)
```

[RODBC odbcDriverConnect() Connection Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420999/rodbc-odbcdriverconnect-connection-error)

https://andersspur.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/connect-r-to-sql-server-2012-and-14/

Give it a try on your side.

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem I'm having is finding the correct driver to setup the ODBC connection. The Windows OS has a built-in driver. Mac OS does not.