# connecting to Oracle DB using Windows authentication / trusted connection in R

Tags: r, odbc

There are a lot of examples how to connect to an Oracle DB using password authentication (i.e. user id + password) in R. However, I need to figure out to set up the connection using [Windows authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/authen.htm#g1010864) / a trusted connection in R for an Oracle DB.

**Example**

I saw a [similar case for a MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420999/rodbc-odbcdriverconnect-connection-error) DB where a connection string is specified containing `trusted_connection=true` which, if I understand correctly, indicates Windows authentication / a trusted conenction.

```
library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=servername\\\\instancename,port;database=testing;trusted_connection=true')
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from information_schema.tables')
```

1) How exactly would that look like for Oracle DB using the information below?

**Additional info (maybe useful):**

In the [`tsnames.ora`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) config file I added the following database address, which works using MS Access.

```
DBNAME.XXX.COM =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DBNAME.XXX.COM)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = DBNAME.XXX.COM)
    )
  )
```

Comment: DId you google, "oracle connect windows authentication" because there are a zillion results.

Comment: Yes. But did not understand how to do it in r. That is  BTW why I took the time to formulate this question in the first place... So any helpful advice?

Comment: I assume that you want to authenticate remotely, correct?  Oracle deprecated remote OS authentication as of 11g due to security concerns. Good discussion here with why that's an issue: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299/why-is-os-authentication-considered-poor-security-for-oracle-databases

Comment: hhm, in our company I log into the Orcale DB via os authentication when I use MS Access. So I would assume that it should also be possible doing the same using R as well, or am I wrong there?

Comment: @krisjohnston I want to log on over  VPN. I am not sure if that would be remotely or not.

Comment: If you are logging in over the network, that is considered remote (from one machine to another).